# Specific x-axis / facet order ggpubr

Tags: r, ggpubr

How do I rearrange the order of the x-axis and the facet on ggpubr?

For example I have the following code for the following graph

```
ggbarplot(Cue, x = "Primary_Dx", y = "Target.RT", fill ="Primary_Dx", palette = "jco", add = "mean_se", facet.by = "Cue", 
          legend.title = "Diagnosis", title = "Average Response Time per Cue",
          xlab = "Diagnosis", ylab = "Average Response Time") + 
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons, label = "p.signif", label.y = c(305, 325, 350)) +
  theme_linedraw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

How do I rearrange the x-axis so it is in the following order: "Depressed", "Anxious", "Healthy".

And the facet so it is "Neutral", "Loss", "Win"

Thank you!

Comment: reorder the factor levels in the data with `forcats::fct_reorder` or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of it can be done by passing in `levels`:

```
vids$mental <- factor(vids$publish_when, levels=c("Depressed", "Anxious", "Healthy"))
vids$outcome <- factor(vids$outcome, levels=c("Neutral", "Loss", "Win"))
```

Extra tip: Do the same for any variables you wish to order, if it matters that your plotting would follow / reflect that necessary order.

If the factor is an ordered factor (`Hot`, `Medium`, `Cool`) or risk level, use `ordered` instead. This order will then be respected in your visualization.

`ggplot` or `ggpubr` is actually not the issue.

Comment: You don't need `ordered`, just use `factor`. All factors have an order for the levels, but if you create an `ordered` object you'll get polynomial contrasts in any modeling instead of the usual reference level contrasts.

Comment: You are correct @Gregor. I was considering the OP's context (Depressed, Anxious, Healthy) and it was actually an ordered categorical hence my suggestion. But I agree - for purely visual / cosmetic change a `levels` parameter should suffice. Updated the answer.